# how do I extract a input string literal containing escape sequences like \a,\16 as a raw string?

Tags: python, rawstring

I want to extract the following input text as raw string but for both r''+ string, repr(string) \a,\1 are getting replaced with \x07,\x01. Will appreciate some help

```
input_txt = 'ab\a\1'
t1=r''+input_txt
t2=repr(input_txt)
print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Comment: i am looking for ab\a\1

Comment: Can you please show an example of the output you are looking for?

Comment: i want to read a  path from a text and use it as it is to proceed further. so for the above example of txt='ab\a\1'  i want some method so that i extract ab\a\1 as it is with out processing of escape sequences or with out replacing a with x07

Answer (score 0):

Raw string is created by prefixing a string literal with ‘r’ or ‘R’.

```
input_txt = r'ab\a\1'
t1 = input_txt
t2 = repr(input_txt)
print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Comment: i can't prefix r directly, since it is an input string.

Comment: You could also escape the backslash with another backslash. Your string will look like this: 'ab\\a\\1'

Comment: but **input_txt.replace('\\','\\\\')** is not giving me the output 'ab\\a\\1'. how can I add another backslash to the string with out doing it manually

Comment: Maybe you can explain a little more about what you want to achieve. How is the input_txt generated and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: I am taking message sent by user as input_txt and trying to extract some portion of input_text which includes escape sequences like i mentioned with a regular expression

Comment: Pass the result of repr() to eval() to get the original object: eval(repr(input_txt)). Hope this helps

Comment: with eval() escape sequences are processed. It is not being returned as a raw string.

Comment: Maybe you can disallow using backslash or replace it with some other character when accepting the user input

Comment: I  can't do that since i want the text as it is to process further.

Answer (score 0):

In the Python Raw string, we usually write the word within the quotes, and in addition to it, we add the literal ‘r’ as the prefix to it, and then we assign it to a variable and print that variable.
All the Raw strings must contain the literal ‘r’ at its prefix.

Comment: i can't add 'r' as prefix  beforehand as input is take from user